# Help in converting AA script to C++

Tags: c++

I've this AA script (Cheat Engine scripting language):

```
[ENABLE]
alloc(newmem,2048) //2kb should be enough
label(returnhere)
label(exit)

00415e19:
jmp newmem

returnhere:
newmem:
mov [00451104],0//moves 0 to the clock variable
//nop//nops the clock increaser

exit:
jmp returnhere

[DISABLE]
dealloc(newmem)
00415e19:
mov [00451104],eax
//Alt: db A3 04 11 45 00
```

It's working - stopping the game clock. Now, I'm trying to convert this code to C++. Here's what I did so far:

```
#include <windows.h>

HWND FindIcyTower()
{
    return FindWindowA(NULL, "Icy Tower v1.4");
}

void WPM(HWND hWnd,int address, byte *data, int dataSize)
{
    DWORD proc_id;
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, &proc_id);

    HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, proc_id);

    if(!hProcess) 
        return;

    WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, (LPVOID)address, data, dataSize, NULL);

    CloseHandle(hProcess); 
}

void EnableClockHack()
{
    WPM(FindIcyTower(), 0x00415E19, {0xc7, 0x05, 0x04, 0x11 ,0x45, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00}, 9);
}

void DisableClockHack()
{
    WPM(FindIcyTower(), 0x00415E19, {0xA3, 0x04, 0x11, 0x45, 0x00}, 4);
}
```

but it crashes the game, instead of stopping the clock. Any ideas?return FindWindowA(NULL, "Icy Tower v1.4");

Comment: `!IcyTower` and `NULL` are the same. Just do `return IcyTower;`; or shorter yet `return FindWindowA(NULL, "Icy Tower v1.4");`

Comment: Thanks, fixed. But any ideas why is it crashing the game?

Comment: Cheating in Icy Tower, naughty man :D

Comment: Looks like both your WPM calls passes an array size one less than what you are actually passing. Not sure if that is intentional though. Might consider using an std::vector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The opcode for moving an immediate (like you are trying to do) is longer (9 bytes) than the game's original code that moves from a register (4 bytes). The extra 5 bytes are most likely overwriting an instruction or two after the original mov causing the program to crash.

Just like in Cheat Engine you'll need to allocate new memory in the target process in which to place your modification code so you don't overwrite any of the game's code. Since this memory will be used by the processor for execution it will need to have the execute bit set.

Once you have your mod code injected you can then change the game's original `mov [00451104],eax` to a jmp to the mod code start address. The the last instruction in the mod code would need to be a jmp back to the instruction just after your replacement jmp which would resume the game executing.

See [VirtualAllocEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366890(VS.85).aspx) for allocating memory in other processes, [VirtualProtectEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366899(VS.85).aspx) for setting PAGE_EXECUTE on that memory, and of course [VirtualFreeEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366894(VS.85).aspx) for releasing the memory when you're done with it.

Answer (score 0):

No idea about the syntax of the AA script, but I got few points:

```
mov [00451104],0
```

Should translate as 'move the intermediate value of 0 to the location 00451104'. And your C++ code reads:

```
WPM(FindIcyTower(), 0x00415E19, {0xc7, 0x05, 0x04, 0x11 ,0x45, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00}, 9);
```

Why are you using the intermediate `{0xc7, 0x05, 0x04, 0x11 ,0x45, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00}` instead of `0` ( `{0,0,0,0}` ) ?

You may also need to read the value from the offset `0x00415E19` first (which is probably what the AA code does implicitly by prefixing the `mov` instruction with the name of the allocated buffer), so you can later restore the original value in the `Disable...` function.